# How to add "<p>" as a tag value at XSLT

Tags: xslt, radeditor

Here is the example code in XSLT:

```
<telerik:EditorParagraph Title="Normal" Tag="<p>"></telerik:EditorParagraph>
```

I get this error "XML Element is not closed".

I am following Telerik's advice to change paragraph style values. The link is here [Using the Paragraphs Collection Declaratively.](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-paragraph-styles.html)

I define Radeditor via XSLT.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT file has to be well-formed XML - to include a less-than sign in an attribute value you must represent it as an entity reference:

```
<telerik:EditorParagraph Title="Normal" Tag="&lt;p>">
```

(you can, and most examples will, also replace the greater-than sign with `&gt;` but this is not strictly required - the only things that *must* be escaped are `<`, `&`, double quotes within a double-quoted attribute and single quotes within a single-quoted attribute).